# Android: Updating textviews in multiple activities

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I need some pointers on doing the following:

- lets say i have 10/20 (number doesn't matter) of activities.
- each of these activities has a textview that should work like a counter.
- each of these activities has a button to go to the next activity.
- this counter starts when the app is launched, and increment itself every second.

So what i did so far is:

- have in my main activity a method that instantiate a class that extends Thread.
- In that class in the run() method, i increment a variable when a second passes.

Now i'm stuck on what i should do next. Any pointers would be appreciated thanks.

Edit: i need a way to communicate from inside the run method, to whichever activity is now currently on screen, to update its textview.

Comment: you can use shared preferences or pass this number to each activity using the `intent.putExtra()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Just a bit of theory here for standard `Object Oriented Programming` : stick to the recommended principles like **Loose Coupling** which makes your project code less tied to each other. You can read more on that later.

Now, using `Events`, you can setup a system that is synonymous with the natural `Publisher/Subscriber` design pattern. Like this:

The activity that needs to `notify` the other activities is called `Publisher` and the other activities that need to be `notified` are called `Subscribers`.

From here:

There are already built and tested libraries to do **Events** in android. Like my favorite `EventBus`.

**Step 1** Add this line to your `app-level build.gradle` file:

```
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
```

Then create a simple `Plain Old Java Object` aka `POJO` class like this:

```
public class UpdateTextViewEvent{
    private String textToShow;

    public UpdateTextViewEvent(String text){
       this.textToShow = text;
    }

    //add your public getters and setters here
}
```

**Step 2** Notify others:

When you want to notify anyone of the changes, you simply called this method:

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new UpdateTextViewEvent("Some new Text"));
```

**Step 3** Receive notifications

For those who want to be notified of this event, simply do this:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
   super.onStart();
   EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
   super.onStop();
   EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}
```

NOTE: to actually handle the event:

```
@Subscribe
public void onEvent(UpdateTextViewEvent event){

   String text = event.getTextToShow();

   //now you can show by setting accordingly on the TextView;

}
```

This is so much easier to do, do decouple your code by eliminating `static` references in your different activities

I hope this helps! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is inside the counter class, create an a method and passed in a `TextView` as the parameter. Then create an int variable and set the counter as the instance:

Like this

```
   public static class Counter extends Thread{
        private static int x;
        @Override
        public void run(){
            x = counter;
        }

        public void setCounter(TextView tv){
            tv.setText(String.valueOf(x));
        }
    }
```

Now call this method `setCounter(TextView)` in all the activity's `onCreate()` method you'll like to display the counter, and passed in your the layout TextView as the argument. Like this

```
...
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState):
....
TextView cTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.texT1);
Counter c = new Counter();
c.setCounter(cTextView);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

make that Textview in second class as

```
  public static Textview text;
```

and call it in main activity as

```
  SecondActivity obj=new SecondActivity();
    obj.text.settext("");
```

Comment: This is too much coupling;

Comment: This won't work at all... you can't create Activity objects with the constructor.